# Using provider in ancestor

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am using provider package to manage state in Flutter.

This is main.dart:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Application>(
      builder: (_) => Application(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomeScreen(),
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.home
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, how can I use the application provider in main.dart? I tried doing `final app = Provider.of<Application>(context).app;` in build function. However, it throws the following error:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Application> above this MyApp Widget

To fix, please:

  * Ensure the Provider<Application> is an ancestor to this MyApp Widget
  * Provide types to Provider<Application>
  * Provide types to Consumer<Application>
  * Provide types to Provider.of<Application>()
  * Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
  * Ensure the correct `context` is being used.
```

I know that the provider can be accessed by the children but is there any way to access in ancestor/main.dart as well? I need to manage an app wide state.

Answer (score 2):

That's what `Consumer` is here for.

You can use it to do:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Whatever>(
    builder: (_) => Whatever(),
    child: Consumer<Whatever>(
      builder: (_, whatever, __) {
        // todo: use `whatever`
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: How do I call provider methods? For example, generally I do -> `Provider.of<Application>(context).getApp();`. Now what should I do in this case?